# Cannot delete entity from database (Entity Framework 4.1)

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-database-first

I have been trying desperately to delete an item from the database but have so far been unable to get it to work. The error message I see is this one:

```
"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable."
```

I am using EF4.1, with EDMX (Database first) and POCO objects. I have a repository for each type and a general repository that implements the base methods.

The specific problem is when I want to delete an item. Deleting the children is not a problem - everything works perfectly - the problem is when I come to delete the entity itself.

Consider the following model. I have an entity "Foo" which has a 1 to many relationship with "Bar". I call the following method in my repository:

```
    public override void Delete(Models.Foo entity)
    {
        //Load the child items...
        base.Context.Entry(entity).Collection(x => x.Bars).Load();

        //Bar
        BarRepository barRep = new BarRepository();
        foreach (var item in entity.Bars)
        {
            var obj = barRep.GetById(item.ID);
            barRep.Delete(obj);
        }            

        barRep.Save();

        //First attempt
        //base.Delete(entity);
        //base.Save();

        //Have to resort to some SQL
        base.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("delete from Foo where ID = {0}", entity.ID));
    }
```

The GenericRepository "Delete" method is:

```
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
```

The GenericRepository "Save" method is simply:

```
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What I would like to get to work is this:

```
        //First attempt
        //base.Delete(entity);
        //base.Save();
```

But unfortunately the only way (currently) for me to delete the item is to run some SQL which just calls _entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL).

I've read a lot of things but nothing seems to work. I would really appreciate some help in trying to understand what is going on.

Thanks,

Jose

Comment: Can't you configure cascaded delete?

Comment: @GertArnold - what do you mean exactly? I thought that the cascade delete would be for the relations rather than the actual entity. Thanks.

Comment: Delete the parent and cascade delete the children.

Comment: I've implemented specific delete methods so that I can perform some auditing tasks as I need this level of control. By using "cascade" will I lose this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know your auditing methods, but they are in the context itself (e.g. SaveChanges override) you should be OK. Try!